# Snap store app are not installing through the online snap store

Tags: snap-store

Snaps not working

Snaps not working

I recently updated my software and now I can’t install any snaps from the online snap store.

If I choose to download from the store it tells me

Failed to install:not supported

And if I try to install it through terminal it tells me

error: cannot install “the app name” :Post
https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io no such host

If anyone could help me fix this I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling snapd :
$ sudo apt-get install snapd

and run

$ systemctl enable --now snapd apparmor

Restart your system and It should work

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same problem persists.

Comment: It can be local DNS issue, what does this URL in browser shows you : https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh
if it gives error 405 fine,the error is from your machine , if it shows some unreachable sort of thing its not at your machine level